# sql server 2005 and .net query

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

First I'll explain the concept of the tables.. 
I have 3 tables, **A, B** and **C**

table A contains the **old and new license numbers** and also the **date** when the driver changed a new license

table A contains

```
fdate                      |   oldLicense (varchar)  |  newLicense  (varchar)  
12/14/2013 4:16:16 PM      |   2                     |  3
```

Table B records the **license number and car ID**, also the **first day** when they used the car. Notice that on 12/14/2013, a new license number is inserted which means that the **drivers were changed on a car** (*because the old one cannot drive anymore  or have died*).

table B contains

```
ID_Car    |    licenseNumber  | fDate
44        |    2              | 12/9/2013 4:16:16 AM   
44        |    3              | 12/14/2013 4:16:16 PM
```

Table C is the maintenance made on the car. Notice that it has dates, **it should reflect when the drivers are changed**. 
 ***Eg, on 12/9/2013 the driver's license is still 2, and on 12/15/2013 the license is already 3.***

table C contains

```
Invoice   |   ID_Car   |   fDate
00989     |   44       |   12/9/2013 5:00:00 AM
10100     |   44       |   12/9/2013 6:00:00 AM
32323     |   44       |   12/15/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

**Desired output:**

```
C.Invoice |  A.Licenses ( old and new?)
00989     |  2  
10100     |  2
32323     |  3
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
SELECT B.fInvoice, C.fLicenseNew 
FROM tblCarFranchise A
LEFT JOIN tblCarMaintenance B ON A.ID_Car = B.ID_Car
LEFT JOIN tblTaxiDriversRelation C ON A.fLicenseNumber = C.fLicenseNew
```

Output:

```
00989     |  NULL  
10100     |  NULL
32323     |  NULL
00989     |  3  
10100     |  3
32323     |  3
```

I dont really know how should I start this, this might be the most complex query that I faced so far, also the rows are somehow duplicated (a total of 6 rows instead of 3 rows)

Help T_T

**UPDATE:**
@Szymon thnx for helping, also to kumarch1 
**on the image, license number 222333 = 2 (on the question) and 13213113 = 3**
[image: Added tables]

Comment: check answer defined below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification, this will be your query. It finds the change of licence based on date.

```
select C.fInvoice, B.fLicenseNumber 
from tblCarMaintenance C
inner join tblCarFranchise B
on C.ID_Car = B.ID_Car
and C.fDate >= B.fdate
and C.fDate < isnull((select top 1 fDate from tblCarFranchise M where M.fdate > B.fdate
              and M.ID_Car = B.ID_Car), '20991231')
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6568/5)

Comment: can you tell me what '20991231' means on the query?

Comment: Date in the distant future. I'm matching invoices to be between the changes of licences and this is how I find the last licence (it's between last change and year 2099.

Comment: oh okay thanks :) it's working on the fiddle, but I'm still tweaking the code to work on sql server and on my code. I'll mark this answered as soon as I get it :)

Comment: I have already edited the question.. thank you so much for the help and sorry for the bother.. I have highlighted the used fields :((
http://i.stack.imgur.com/mhwXb.png

Comment: Updated the answer. I made a wrong assumptions that licences are consecutive. Now I compare based on dates. Remove some of your comments as well, let's clean that post up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

keep your data in a temp temple and retrieve data from temp table without null

```
Select temp.fInvoice ,temp.fLicenseNew from( SELECT B.fInvoice as fInvoice , C.fLicenseNew as  fLicenseNew 
FROM tblCarFranchise A
LEFT JOIN tblCarMaintenance B ON A.ID_Car = B.ID_Car
LEFT JOIN tblTaxiDriversRelation C ON A.fLicenseNumber = C.fLicenseNew) temp
where temp.fLicenseNew != null
```